# python find exact string

Tags: python, regex, list, find

I want to find in a list an exact match. I do :

```
if any (myword in s for s in listeWord):
   print myword
```

for example I have the word : `"11848_3"` and it find in my list : `"8_3"`, I don't want that, I want the exact word. I often find this problem and I resolve it with regex, but for this case I can't (I suppose).

Comment: Simply: `if myword in listeWord` ?

Comment: `if myword in listeWord: print myword`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, just do

```
if myword in listeWord:
    print myword
```

The `in` keyword will check if an element is contained in a *sequence*.

Answer (score 1):

syntax for that:

```
if substring in string:
    print(True)
else:
    pass    #any code you want
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am just getting used to stack overflow. thanks for telling though